# Quotation in csv library

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to request an XML API for the first column in the input tsv file, and get a tsv file as output.

My input file(tab separated):

```
input1   input1.1   input1.2   input1.3
input2   input2.1   input2.2   input2.3
```

The code:

```
with open('data/input.txt', 'r') as tsvin, open('data/output.txt', 'w') as csvout:
    tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
    csvout = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    for i in tsvin:
        word = i[0]
        r = requests.get(api_url + str(word), params=payload)

        root = ElementTree.fromstring(r.content)

        for child in root.iter('entry'):
            if child.attrib['id'] == word + word_id or child.attrib['id'] == word:
                for child_nested in child:
                    if child_nested.tag == 'pr':
                        csvout.writerow([i, child_nested.text])
```

As a result I got:

```
['input1', 'input1.1', 'input1.2', 'input1.3']  value_from_api1
['input2', 'input2.1', 'input2.2', 'input2.3']  value_from_api2
```

If I do `csvout.writerow([i])` at the end, the initial row writes to the output properly without any quotation. But if I added the result from API `child_nested.text` after the comma, it writes with quotes.

So, how to append `child_nested.text` to i and write it without quotes?

Comment: What is the wrong output?  Provide example input, desired output, and actual output - it's hard to help without seeing exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I had sort of hard time with comment formatting here )
Thanks for quick response @Andrew_reece

I just want to ge (tab separated)t:
input1  input1.1  input1.2  input1.3  value_from_api1
input2  input2.1  input2.2  input2.3 value_from_api2

The input file is tab separated values without quotes.

Comment: This is probably a simple fix.  One reason why no one's jumped in to help yet is because it's hard to know what the problem is, the way you've written your question.  You'll get better help, faster, if you include a small, representative example input data set in your post (not in a comment), and show how the code you've posted takes that example data and produces the wrong output you're having trouble with.  If you do that, others can help you debug the problem.  Remember to include your import statements. 
 Also, can you use Pandas?

Comment: Thank you for your patience and suggestions, Andrew. I've edited initial post and done my best to be clearer. Regarding Pandas, I suppose I can, though I don't know how, yet.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> If I do `csvout.writerow([i])` at the end, the initial row writes to the output properly without any quotation.

This is only true if you write `i` without the list wrapper `[]`.  Using `outfile.writerow(i)` the contents of `output.txt` conform to your desired format:

```
input1  input1.1    input1.2    input1.3
input2  input2.1    input2.2    input2.3
```

The easiest way to add on `child_nested.text`, given that `child_nested.text` is a string, is to add it to `i`, like this:

```
outfile.writerow(i + ['foo'])
```

Now, `output.txt` looks like your desired output:

```
input1  input1.1    input1.2    input1.3    foo
input2  input2.1    input2.2    input2.3    foo
```

Comment: You're welcome!  If this answer resolved your issue, please mark it accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the question.  (You can also upvote too, if you found it helpful.)

Comment: Sorry, Andrew but it seems that I a bit jumped to conclusions.
The output file contains  child_nested.text as text (string) at the end of all rows, although it should be a result of r request i.e. variable child_nested.text.